# AngularJS can't interpolate error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting this error in browser:

```
Error: [$interpolate:interr] Can't interpolate: 
        {{ displayName(stream.StreamName) }}

TypeError: undefined is not a function
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.25/$interpolate/interr?p0=%0A%20%20%20%20%2…0A%20%20%20%20%20%20&p1=TypeError%3A%20undefined%20is%20not%20a%20function
```

Code is pretty simple, here is the HTML:

```
<div class="card" ng-repeat="stream in streams">
  <div class="item item-divider">
    {{ displayName(stream.StreamName) }}
  </div>
  <ion-list>
    <div class="item " ng-repeat="(key, value) in stream">
      {{key}}
      <p>
        {{value}}
      </p>
    </div>
  </ion-list>
```

And here is the Controller javascript code:

```
angular.module('starter')
.controller('StreamsCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.displayName = function(s) {
    return s.subString(s.lastIndexOf('/')+1)
  }
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"can't interpolate" wording overwhelmed me :)

When I tried to console.log(), it wouldn't work... and problem was, I misspelled javascript `subString()`. Its not capitalized, its `substring()`.

Only reason to write this question and answer so others know that when you get 'interpolation error', it could be as simple as javascript typo.